# How to set the date format to (dd/mm/yyyy) for a column in excel ,While using ag-grid's export to excel feature with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid

I want to set the date format of the cells to be "dd/mm/yyyy" for a column. Currently the date is stored as a General Format in Excel.

I have already tried using this code in excel styles

```
this.excelStyles = [
{
  id: "dateFormat",
  dataType: "dateTime",
  numberFormat: { format: "dd/mm/yyyy;@" }
}
]
```

But I am getting an error while opening the excel files, and when opened somehow I am getting some junk value for the column.

Comment: excelStyles should be an array of styles, not a single style

Comment: I have tried using array ,but still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Are there any errors on your input at the grid?

Comment: yes, there  are errors in the excel file, the downloaded excel file is not getting opened ,there are errors for the date column

Comment: Can you suggest me an solution for this .

Comment: I mean, are there any input errors when the user input the date? If there are errors, that is probably the reason why it doesn't export properly?

Comment: there are no input errors, I want to know that is my approach correct and if not then what is the correct way  to do it.